# Is there any way to solve this problem in my code?

Tags: c++

Hello dear people I am getting this error in my C++ Code can somebody please help?

Error: `undefined reference to 'Area(int,int)'`

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Area(int length, int width); // prototip funkcije

int main()
{
int lengthOfYard;
int widthOfYard;
int areaOfYard;

cout << "Kolika je sirina vaseg dvorista?\n";
cin >> widthOfYard;
cout << "Kolika je duzina vaseg dvorista\n";
cin >> lengthOfYard;

areaOfYard = Area(lengthOfYard,widthOfYard);

cout << "Povrsina vaseg dvorista je: ";
cout << areaOfYard;
cout << "metara kvadratnih\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the implementation of **Area** function. Also, the prototype of the function **Area** should be  `int Area(int length, int width){  return some_int_value};`

Comment: okay thank you! I finished, it worked perfectly. thanks

Answer (score -2):

Where is the defination for above signature of the function?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int Area(int length, int width); // prototip funkcije

int main() {
    int lengthOfYard;
    int widthOfYard;
    int areaOfYard;

    cout << "Kolika je sirina vaseg dvorista?\n";
    cin >> widthOfYard;
    cout << "Kolika je duzina vaseg dvorista\n";
    cin >> lengthOfYard;

    areaOfYard = Area(lengthOfYard, widthOfYard);

    cout << "Povrsina vaseg dvorista je: ";
    cout << areaOfYard;
    cout << "metara kvadratnih\n\n";

    return 0;
}

int Area(int length, int width) {};
```